# DigitalOcean error while bundle install - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, digital-ocean

I'm getting an error while running bundle install on digitalocean. I've put the error's in a pastebin here; 
http://pastebin.com/wzFCFYYE

Thank you.

Comment: If you have something relevant to the question then please put it *in* the question. External links are annoying and will likely be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Looks similar to [Bundle install: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. nio4r gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859413/bundle-install-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-nio4r-gem)

You probably don't have installed on DigitalOcean some libraries... from the marked as correct answer... probably you need only

```
sudo apt-get install libev-dev
```

Before install the gem

Answer (score -1):

Lets try

```
`sudo gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'`
```

Comment: That got rid of some of the errors, but now I have this; http://pastebin.com/zLv6SDc9

Answer (score -1):

Might be this command will help you -

```
gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'
```

if this command is not working then follow the below steps to fixing this issue like -

**Try to install nio4r with different version** so remove/change version from Gem file. If still getting some issue then remove Gemlock file and run bundle install.

Might be above solution will help you.